# Is there an iPhone 3.0 SDK API for calendar event management?

Tags: ios, iphone, calendar, iphone-sdk-3.0

Is there an API in the iPhone 3.0 (or later) SDK to programmatically create and manage calendar events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Not much more I can say, unfortunately. It might be a good idea to file a bug/feature request with Apple - a version of the Mac OS Calendar Store framework on iPhone would be a great addition.